# Django Image Upload Not Working Properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

my database is getting updated with image name with path, but image hasn't been uploaded in the specified folder. Am new to Django, Pls help if am wrong with my coding. below is my code :

```
Model.py:
class MasterBank(models.Model):
    bankid            = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
    bankname          = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    banklogourl       = models.ImageField(upload_to ='images/', blank=True)

views.py :
class imageUpload(APIView):
    def  post(self,request):
        checkReq = request.FILES['banklogourl']
        m = MasterBank.objects.get(pk=1)
        m.banklogourl = checkReq
        m.save()
        return HttpResponse('image upload success')
Urls:
url(r'^imageupload/$', views.imageUpload.as_view(), name="imageUpload"),
```

Comment: How are your `MEDIA_ROOT` settings set up?

Comment: images folder is present at same folder where the views and models file reside.

Comment: lets see your settings; as the image will be uploaded in MEDIA_ROOT, 'images/'

Comment: The `MEDIA_ROOT` still needs to be defined in **settings.py**

Comment: yes.. you are correct.. Pls post the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media path should be specified in settings.py

MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

## The above is the media folder where the images are stored with folder specified in models.